# How to run "Eclipse Che" behind NGINX reverse proxy?

Tags: java, eclipse, nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have installed on a server Eclipse Che and it runs perfectly on my machine when I use it locally **localhost:8080**

I would like to make it available from the Internet, behind a NGINX front reverse proxy. Here is the idea:

**example.com/che/**  ---> **NGINX reverse proxy** ---> **server:8080/**

I tried so many different NGINX configuration... without success.
For information, Eclipse Che embeds a Tomcat instance with some rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/api/ext/(.*)$ /ide/ext/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ /ide/api/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /dashboard [R]
```

There are 3 webapps deployed on the Tomcat server:

```
ide
dashboard 
swagger
```

If Eclipse Che is behind NGINX, the above rewrite rules are useless and can be done directly by NGINX (that's what I did)

I would like to have one single block in my NGINX configuration (if possible) Here is what I tried to do so far, but it's not fully working and Eclipse Che does not load fully (my guess is that WebSockets are not proxified, and I miss something) Basically, I tried to "proxypass" the different webapps, but this may not be the best option.

```
location /dashboard {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/dashboard;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
location /ide {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/ide;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
location /api {
 rewrite ^/api/ext/(.*)$ /ide/ext/$1 redirect;
 rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /ide/api/$1 redirect;
}
```

You can notice I added the rewrite rules in the NGINX "api" location rather than in the Tomcat configuration (ROOT webapp)
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

FYI http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

You have to add a websocket connection upgrade specific conf:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
            default upgrade;
            ''      close;
        }

proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
```

Comment: Thanks, I added these lines to my configuration file, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Even with WebSocket support you'll have issues to reverse proxy the [randomly assigned ports in range 32768‒65535 and the optional SSH port](https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/networking) (the later is only useful if you want to connect directly via SSH to your runtime).

Currently the only practical and safe solution I see is by making a VPN.

It's however [on the roadmap](https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/1560) of Che improvements.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Apache, using apache http proxy based forwarding.
I was then able to go to http://che.xyz.com/ and use che from there.
Oh, and I did have to map che.xyz.com to my server's ip address.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName che.xyz.com
    ServerAlias che.xyz.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ...
    ...
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```